# Where i can find VSCode ionic AutoComplete?

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

Is there an autocomplete for Ionic Framework on Visual Studio Code?
I tried to search everywhere but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ionic1-snippets extension. You can install that via Code itself. More info may be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=justinjames.ionic1-snippets.

Comment: I'm used to <ion- and then hit Ctrl + Space and it shows a list of alternatives i can use. 
But the extension you linked seems to work really good. Once i get used to it, will probably make my workflow much better.
Marked as correct answer and will upvote when i have enough repo.
Thanks.